# WSO2 ESB Proxy CRLF normalized to LF

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, wso2-esb

A simple proxy that only adds authentication.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="QueryTestProxy"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                   name="Authorization"
                   expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode(fn:concat('admin:', wso2:vault-lookup('QueryTest'))))"
                   scope="transport"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint key="conf:/QueryTest"/>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <faultSequence>
         <send/>
      </faultSequence>
   </target>
   <publishWSDL key="conf:/WSDL/QueryTest.wsdl"/>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

The endpoint service does a split on CRLF on one of the fields, also the endpoint can not be modified and can't use CDATA.

The problem is that WSO2 ESB always replaces CRLF with LF and the split won't work, does anyone know a way to stop WSO2 ESB to normalize the message?

Answer (score 2):

Axiom uses stax and stax remove those CR in CR-LF

I've had a similar issue when writing text files from a soap message generated like this :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:guid="http://com/cylande/unitedretail/guidedsale/service/common/GuidedSaleManagerService/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <text xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">my flat datas whith carriage return and line feeds</text>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

We should be able to configure this behavior creating a **XMLOutputFactory.properties** file inside ESB_HOME, with this content : **com.ctc.wstx.outputEscapeCr=false**
But in my case, I were not able to start the ESB any more...

(See http://ws.apache.org/axiom/apidocs/org/apache/axiom/om/util/StAXUtils.html for more details)

Here is the javascrip that I've added in my mediation before calling send mediator :

```
<script language="js"><![CDATA[
        try {           
            var payloadXML = mc.getPayloadXML();            
            var envelopeXML = mc.getEnvelope();         
            if (payloadXML != null) {               
                var text = payloadXML.toString();               
                if ((envelopeXML != null) && (envelopeXML.getBody() != null) && (envelopeXML.getBody().getFirstElement() != null))                          
    // Do not use mc.setPayloadXML(), it depends on Stax that delete the carriage return we are trying to add...
                    envelopeXML.getBody().getFirstElement().setText(text.replace(new RegExp('\n','g'),'\r\n'));         
            }       
        } catch (e) {           
        }
]]></script>
```

Hope you will be able to adapt this script to your need.

Comment: I tried using javascript mediator, it replaces LF with CRLF in the text of that node, but when the message is sent, it is replaced back with LF.

Answer (score 0):

ESB's XML parser (AXIOM) is just working according to XML specification

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-line-ends

So XML parser must replace CR-LF with LF. This is mentioned in above XML spec .

This is the reason of replacing CRLF with LF in wso2 ESB